# Why there is no version 6.0.0 final of Microsoft.Win32.Registry nuget package?

Tags: package, nuget, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

The latest version of the *Microsoft.Win32.Registry* package is [6.0.0-preview.5.21301.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/6.0.0-preview.5.21301.5#versions-body-tab) released on 15th June 2021 and there is no .NET 7.0 preview version as well. However the Microsoft doc explains that the class [Microsoft.Win32.Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=net-6.0) is available for .NET 6.0 and .NET 7.0 preview in the assembly *Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll*.

The package [System.Security.Principal.Windows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Principal.Windows/) has exactly the same versioning issue while the doc says that the class [System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal?view=net-6.0) is available for .NET 6.0 and .NET 7.0 preview in the assembly *System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll*.

On the other hand the package [System.Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/) for example is available for .NET 6.0 and .NET 7.0 preview.

**What is happening with *Microsoft.Win32.Registry* and *System.Security.Principal.Windows* packages?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` change your target framework to `net6.0-windows` - as answered in [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/62055):

> You shouldn't need an extra package. If you set `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>` in your .csproj, you should get access to those types.

Comment: Thanks! what about if the project is netstandard2.0? It used to reference Microsoft.Win32.Registry 5.0.0 seamlessly.

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam as far as I remember Microsoft (and community =))) changed how the dependencies and cross platform stuff is handled (again).  .netstandard2.0 projects should be referencing the latest appropriate package. For ongoing development maybe it will be worth considering multitargeting and using correct TFMs. See [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/) blogpost and [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks).