# Visual Studio giving errors about incompatible packages that are not installed

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have an ASP.NET Blazor server-side solution that I have been working on on my main dev machine for months.

I just pulled the code from source control onto my lap top. However, VS gives errors like this...

*Package Microsoft.Win32.Registry 5.0.0 is not compatible with net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0). Package Microsoft.Win32.Registry 5.0.0 does not support any target frameworks.*

I get these errors for every project in the solution, along with similar errors for `System.Security.Principal.Windows` and `Humanizer.Core`.

However, as far as I can see, none of these packages are referenced anywhere in the solution. I haven't referenced them, and looking through all the dependencies I have, I can't see any of these three as dependencies of referenced packages.

The only differences I can see between my dev machine and my lap top are that the dev machine is on Win7 with VS2022 17.4.0, whereas the lap top is Win11 with VS2022 17.4.1.

Anyone any ideas?

In case it helps, here is the full `.csproj` file for one of the projects. I get all three errors in this project...

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="LanguageExt.Core" Version="4.2.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Pixata.Extensions" Version="1.23.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.CommonHelpers\OneGiv.CommonHelpers.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example to reproduce this problem? Does it useful to delete nuget cache?

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT Not sure how I would provide an example. This is a solution that works fine on my main dev machine (and for other developers on theirs), but gives this error on my lap top. Tried clearing the nuget cache, but it didn't help. Thanks, any other ideas?

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT I added the contents of one of the project files in case that helps

Comment: You can try to change the TargetFramework to <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624188/why-there-is-no-version-6-0-0-final-of-microsoft-win32-registry-nuget-package). You can try it, hope it works.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't make any difference. However I still don't understand why it's even trying to access these packages when I haven't added them (and I can't see that any of my dependencies do.

Comment: Thought I was onto something. VS just told me that in order to get the best experience (whatever that means), I needed to add some missing workflow types. VS Installer popped up and asked me to install the .NET Desktop workflow. No idea why, as this solution only has ASP.NET and MAUI projects, but given that the errors included Microsoft.Win32.Registry, I thought I'd give it a go. Sadly it didn't help.

Comment: Anyone? I'm completely stuck. I've downloaded a fresh copy of the source code, cleaned my solution, deleted bin, obj and .vs folders, , cleared the Nuget cache, but nothing seems to help

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel, did you get anywhere with this? I'm having a seemingly identical issue - bizarre "xxx is not compatible) when it clearly is, and my other laptop is building the exact same revision perfectly fine...

Comment: @ImmortalBlue No, in the end I had to rebuild the project from scratch